# Header not repeating after page break

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, datagrid

I added a page break after every 20 rows in a DataGrid. After the page break I want to display the header on top of each page. 
I added a `thead` tag around the header:

```
    <thead>
     <tr id="trHeader" runat="server">
          <td style="border-width:1px;text-align:left;padding:10px;font-size:26px;">
           <div>
                <strong><label runat="server" id="lblInvCredNo"></label>&nbsp;</strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuoteNo"></asp:Label>
           </div>
         </td>
        <td style="border-width:1px;text-align:left;padding:10px;font-size:26px;">
         <div>
          <strong><label runat="server" id="lblIvnCredDate"></label>&nbsp;</strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuoteDate"></asp:Label>
          </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
 </thead>
```

I added code to the css:

```
@media print {
    .pagebreak  { 
        page-break-after:always;          
    }

    thead {display: table-header-group;}
}
```

To put the page break after the 20th row in the grid I used this code:

```
private int count = 1;
    public void dgDetails_Bind(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            if ((count % 20) == 0)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[e.Item.Cells.Count - 1].Text = e.Item.Cells[e.Item.Cells.Count - 1].Text +
                                                            "</td><tr class=\"pagebreak\"><td colspan='" +
                                                            e.Item.Cells.Count + "'><div class=\"pagebreak\"></div>";
                e.Item.CssClass = "pagebreak";

            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Do I need to add something to this function to show the header after the page break?

Comment: Are you including the closing `td` and `tr` tags in the output?

Comment: @DaveB what do you mean? Do I need to add more code somewhere?

Comment: The string you are assigning to the `Text` property of the cell has opening `tr` and `td` tags but doesn't include the closing tags. I wondered if that might be an issue. Not really sure!